# Boolean expressions and functions that take functions as arguments in SML

Tags: functional-programming, sml

The meaning of the expression ***'f 7'*** in function ***1)*** below is unclear to me.  Unless I use function ***3)***, which always evaluates to ***false***, it always resolves to ***true***.  Which is to say, when I pass it function ***2)*** and function ***2)*** should resolve to ***false***, i.e., when x <=0, the else branch--in this case the expression ***fn x => 3*x***--fails to execute.  I think there's probably something obvious that I'm missing... any hints would be greatly appreciated.

1)

```
fun double_or_triple f = 
    if f 7
    then fn x => 2*x
    else fn x => 3*x
```

2. 

```
fun st x = if x > 0 then true else false
```

3. 

```
fun always_false (x:int) = false;
```

***Addendum:***
Using @Simon Shine's method with function ***2)*** makes it absolutely clear what's going on:

```
double_or_triple st 6
-> (if st 7 then fn x => 2 * x else fn x => 3 * x) 6    
-> (if (if (7 > 0) then true else false) then fn x => 2 * x else fn x => 3 * x) 6   
-> (if (if true then true else false) then fn x => 2 * x else fn x => 3 * x) 6  
-> (if true then fn x => 2 * x else fn x => 3 * x) 6    
-> (fn x => 2 * x) 6    
-> 2*6  
-> 12
```

Comment: `x` in the second function is `7`, which is (always) `> 0`. You'd need to pass a different function than `st`, one which returns `false` for the input `7`, to get the tripling function.

Comment: It might help your understanding to rename the parameter `x` of the second function, e.g. to `fun st y = y > 0`

Comment: @Bergi that makes sense.  '7' is obvious enough.  It's a literal value, not a placeholder for any int.  For some reason I was thinking along those lines... Thank you.

Comment: Note that `if x > 0 then true else false` is a wordy equivalent to `x > 0`.

Comment: @Simon Shine noted -- thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unless I use function 3), which always evaluates to false, it always resolves to true.

Take this example:

```
- fun is_even x = (x mod 2 = 0);
- double_or_triple is_even 2;
> val it = 6 : int
```

You can evaluate these things by hand for clarity:

```
double_or_triple is_even 2
  ~> (if is_even 7 then fn x => 2*x else fn x => 3*x) 2
  ~> (if (7 mod 2 = 0) then fn x => 2*x else fn x => 3*x) 2
  ~> (if (1 = 0) then fn x => 2*x else fn x => 3*x) 2
  ~> (if false then fn x => 2*x else fn x => 3*x) 2
  ~> (fn x => 3*x) 2
  ~> 3*2
  ~> 6
```

with `~>` being a hand-made reduction.

Comment: beautifully done!  Thank you very much.  I think I need to bone up on my lambda calculus...